# Cake PHP add get parameters to form

Tags: forms, cakephp, post, get

I want to conditionally add a GET parameter to a form action in CakePHP, but the default action behaviour seems to be overriding what I want it to be set as:

I tried this, which results in `$formaction` being the form action that I want except :

```
$formaction = '/edit/'.$this->data['Shipment']['id'];
$formaction = isset($trace_param)? '?trace_action='.$trace_action.'&trace_param='.$trace_param : '';

echo $this->Form->create('Shipment', array('action'=> $formaction ));
```

That results in the action being `shipments/shipments/edit/7101?trace_action=scheduled_shipments&amp;trace_param=2013-03-18/7101`

So I tried setting the model to null.. but it always appends the shipment id onto the end of the form action.  I also tried just hardcoding the `<form>` tag in html but that results in data not being in the submitted form. When I put it back to the original `echo $this->Form->create('Shipment');` it works again.

Is there a reliable method of appending get parameters to a form in Cake? (The site uses version 1.3.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### action != url

if the [`action` key](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#options-action) is set that's the *controller action* i.e.:

```
/controller_name/<this bit>/other/args
```

To explicitly set the url a form will submit to, use the [`url` key](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#options-url):

```
echo $this->Form->create('Shipment', array('url'=> $formaction));
```

### Don't manipulate urls as strings

Urls in Cake are normally defined as arrays, they are more flexible and easier to work with. The url in the question can be written as:

```
$formaction = array(
    'action' => 'edit',
    $this->data['Shipment']['id']
);

if ($trace_param) {
    $formaction['?'] = array(
        'trace_action' => $trace_action
        'trace_param' => $trace_param

    )
}

echo $this->Form->create('Shipment', array('url'=> $formaction));
```

### Or just use hidden form inputs

Which generally makes life pretty simple:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Shipment');
if ($trace_param) {
    echo $this->Form->hidden('trace_action', array('value' => $trace_action));
    echo $this->Form->hidden('trace_param', array('value' => $trace_param));
}
```

Comment: When I do the method in the middle the form action is: `action="/shipments/Array/7117"`.  I should have mentioned this is cake 1.3.7

Comment: ah got it coo.. now the only trick is that in the form action html it's escaping characters to htmlentities so I get `["amp;trace_param"]=> string(10) "2013-03-18" ` :p

Comment: the `<form>` tag's action attribute is printed as : `action="/shipments/edit/7117?trace_action=scheduled_shipments&amp;trace_param=2013-03-18"`

Comment: I can do an awkward if statement to trim the `amp;` off, though

Comment: ah so it's not valid in html to have a form action that has multiple get parameters in the action then? Interesting.

Comment: I stated the real problem in the second comment.. Cake is telling me any URL parameter beyond the first is amp;parametername when I'm adding them to form actions

Comment: I know you think you are providing all information necessary but quite simply -> [you are not](http://ad7six.com/dump/cake-1.3-get-args.png) <-. Whatever it is you are doing to obtain your get args is wrong/broken. If you still think otherwise - show some code (and probably ask another question) =).

Comment: Not sure why it's not encoding the ampersand properly then. I will just manually filter it. Thanks a lot for the complete answer, made a few things much more clear.